# Aspnetboilerplate - Globalization and localization of Data annotations of entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, abp, aspnetzero

I'm using the `aspnetboilerplate` framework and would like to translate the data model annotations.

I added the code for translation in: `Project.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs`

```
services.AddLocalization(
 options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"
 );
    
services
 .AddMvc()
 .AddViewLocalization()
 .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
 {
  options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
      factory.Create(typeof(DataAnnotationsLang));
 });
```

I added the `DataAnnotationsLang` resource in the directory: `Project.Web.Mvc/Resources/DataAnnotationsLang.cs`

In the `Project.Web.Mvc/Resources/DataAnnotationsLang.pt-PT.resx` file I added the translation

The file has the following structure:

```
<data name="The {0} field is required." xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Translation of field {0}.</value>
    <comment>DataAnnotations RequiredAttribute_ValidationError</comment>
</data>
```

This is not working. I made according to the microsoft website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Did you try the [AbpDisplayNameAttribute](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Localization/AbpDisplayNameAttribute.cs)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it's applicable, what I intend to do is translate the error messages from the "Data Annotations" of the entity framework.

Comment: any progress here @Ana?

Comment: Yes I used it. AbpDisplayName with LocalizationSourceName.
It's hard work but it does the job.

Comment: Update: AbpDisplayName Translates attribute names, but I cannot translate entity framework error messages (Required, StringLength, Range...) with Validator.TryValidateObject. Can anyone translate the entity framework error messages?